# Can anyone Solve for x with c#? floor(x * 1.04) = 258

Tags: c#, math, algebra, floor

I'm adding the floor of 4% to an int in this example 249. It will be a different int every time though.
here is my code for that which works fine.

```
int qty = 249;
qty += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)qty * 0.04));
```

but the problem that comes up is after this sometime later in the program and after I no longer have the original value I need to revert back to the old value using the new value. I cant just subtract 4% because although it works sometimes a lot of the time it is inaccurate. The closest I came to is this

```
double d = Math.Round((double)qty * 0.036);
qty = Convert.ToInt32((double)qty - d);
```

which is accurate most of the time with smaller numbers, but not all the time.
I did come up with an equation that should work if I could solve for x and get a whole number but so far I am stumped on how to solve for x. Here is the equation I came up with **solve for x, floor(x*1.04) = 258** . Can anyone solve that and have it give me a whole number or does anyone have a better idea on how to do this without storing the old value anywhere?
I am well aware that I could store the old value but if it is easily reversible with a simple math problem then I see no reason to store it. Also this will be done on a large list of items so it wouldn't just be storing one original value it would be thousands.

Comment: "without storing the old value anywhere" - no. Store the original value. It might even take less memory than all the intermediate results of your calculations.

Comment: `does anyone have a better idea on how to do this without storing the old value anywhere` That's like asking if anyone got a better idea to launch a bigger rocket to space without carrying additional fuel. You should explain(in your question, not a comment please) why you cannot do the most logical thing and is looking for an abstrud solution?

Comment: Well, Math.Floor will remove significant amount to the _qty_ variable such that returning to a precise value is not possible. However the formula used to separate the percentage increase from a value is _qty = Convert.ToInt32((100 * qty) / (double)104);_ but it will return 248

Comment: Instead if you use a decimal for qty and remove the Math.Floor, returning to the initial value would be precise

Comment: @Steve: The mapping is injective, so it is reversible. Mathematically, you can always recover the original quantity by using `floor((qty + 1.0) / 1.04)`. Numerically, it's possible that there are some corner cases that might cause issues, but I didn't discover any for `qty` up to `10**6`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you that worked well! That is what I was Looking for. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it! I was well aware of the fact that I could store a value but I saw no reason if it was easily reversed.

Comment: @ThomasWeller this will be done on a list of thousands of items so it wouldn't just be storing one value it would be thousands. I clarified that in my question as well.

Comment: @Steve The reason this works is that for every f:R=>R with f being injective it's easy to proof that floor(f): Z=>Z will also be injective. [The proof seems reasonably easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893586/injective-function-proof-involving-floor-function)

Comment: why using floats for this? fixed point is easier and probably much faster (as you do not need to convert back and forward) `qty = (qty*104)/100;` and reverse `qty = (qty*100)/104` .... also if you know how many iteration you do you can use power of `104/100` and `100/104` instead of for loop

Comment: "I am well aware that I could store the old value but if it is easily reversible with a simple math problem then I see no reason to store it." -> on the other hand, there's no reason to store the new value either, since it can be computed from the old value with a simple math formula; and if you store the new value, you have to implement *two* simple math formulas in your code.

Comment: thousands = kB. millions = MB. It's not a problem. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment from @MarkDickinson was the answer I was looking for:

> The mapping is injective, so it is reversible. Mathematically, you can
> always recover the original quantity by using floor((qty + 1.0) /
> 1.04). Numerically, it's possible that there are some corner cases that might cause issues, but I didn't discover any for qty up to
> 10**6.